# How to handle exiting Android app?

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I found a couple of places that suggest System.exit(0), but then I read a couple of places that this is bad practice, since android handles closing an application for you.

My issue is, I have an auto logout function that takes users back to the login page, BUT I'm wondering what's in memory at this time. Do I have to have a de-constructor setup to set my values to null when activities change or do objects automatically get nulled out between activity changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Activity#finish()` when you're done with any Activities. For example, when the auto-logout occurs, call `finish()` on any open Activities.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm using to go from page to page, however if I'm directing people to my login page, how do I finish? Can I start an activity and then finish my current activity? Or finish my current activity then start new activity

Comment: You can do either. You can call `finish()` before or after `startActivity`. You may also direct to your login page with an Activity Intent flag like https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Comment: Any objects in the Activity, yes. `finish()` invokes `onDestroy()` in the Activity.